# Python matplot misses bars in bar graph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

pyhon matplot misses bars in bar graph. I expect it to generate bar at [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000] but it shows only at [250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nsamples = 1000 + 1
vpp = 25
timestamps = [t for t in range(0, nsamples, vpp)]
processings = [0 for t in range(0, nsamples, vpp)]
transmissions = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]

for transmission in transmissions:
    processings[transmission / vpp] = 1

plt.bar(timestamps, processings)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because the bar height is zero in other places! Also you need to give processings[transmission // vpp] for indexing (it should be a index)

Comment: It seems your code is for Python 2.7. Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it working somehow and i don't know details but when i reduced the sample size by using range(0, nsamples/vpp, 1) instead of range(0, nsamples, vpp) then graph was plotted as expected (even though number of elements to be plotted against on x axis was still same.) it seems plt.bar assumes unit step between axis values in argument list instead of just taking the list itself and plotting it.